# Invalid operands and Illegal assignment cast

Tags: c++, casting

The purpose of this program is to take a dollar amount and print the number of bills that would be returned to give that amount most efficiently and the remaining change. (i.e. $523.33 = $50 x 10 / $20 x1 / $1 x 3/ .33 remaining). It should work except for the errors i get in the attached image. I've tried every iteration I've been taught of casting, but nothing works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double withdrawAmount; //declare variable to store use input for desired withdraw amount

    do { //Ask for valid user input
       cout << "Please enter an amount to withdraw from yor account" << endl;
       cin >> withdrawAmount; //save user input into withdrawAmount variable
   } while (withdrawAmount < 1);

   //Print greatest # of bills that can be taken from the withdrawlAmount
     cout << "$50 bills :"<< (int) withdrawAmount / 50 << endl;    
   //Print number of $50 bills
     (int) withdrawAmount %= 50;
     cout << "$20 bills: " << (int) (withdrawAmount %= 50) / 20 << endl; 
   //Print number of $20 bills
     (int) withdrawAmount %= 20;
     cout << "$10 bills: " << (int) (withdrawAmount %= 20) / 10 << endl; 
  //Print number of $10 bills
   (int)withdrawAmount %= 10;
   cout << "$5 bills: " << (int) (withdrawAmount %= 10) / 5 << endl; 
  //Print number of $5 bills
   (int)withdrawAmount %= 5;
   cout << "$1 bills: " << (int) (withdrawAmount %= 5) / 1 << endl; 
  //Print number of $1 bills
   (int) withdrawAmount %= 1;
   cout << "Remaining: " << withdrawAmount / 1 << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You probably want: [std::fmod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod)

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Post text.

Comment: " I've tried every iteration I've been taught of casting, but nothing works."  - C++ is not a trial-and-error language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(int) withdrawAmount %= 50;` should be replaced by

```
withdrawAmount = std::fmod(withdrawAmount, 50);
```

Same for other values. (don't forget `#include <cmath>`).

as alternative:

```
double input; //declare variable to store use input for desired withdraw amount

do { //Ask for valid user input
   cout << "Please enter an amount to withdraw from yor account" << endl;
   cin >> input; //save user input into withdrawAmount variable
} while (input < 1);
int withdrawAmount = input; // rounded toward 0.

std::cout << "$50 bills :"<< withdrawAmount / 50 << std::endl;
withdrawAmount %= 50;

// And so on...

// Final remaining
std::cout << "Remaining: " << input - int(input) << std::endl;
```